# error TS2339: Property 'sendEmailVerification' does not exist on type 'Promise<User>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

so I'm working on my ionic4 app and I am getting an error on the ***sendEmailVerification*** function. The console asks me whether I forgot to use 'await'. What could be the solution? Thanks.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseAuthService {

  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  async registerWithEmailPassword(email, password) {
    try {
      const result = await this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      await this.angularFireAuth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
      return result;
    }catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `currentUser` is a promise, so the solution is probably :

```js
...
      await (await this.angularFireAuth.currentUser).sendEmailVerification();
...
```

Note that the outer `await` is only needed if `sendEmailVerification` returns a promise and you need to wait for it is complete before returning the result.